# How to get gender of currently logged in customer in magento?

Tags: magento

I tried with Mage::getSingleton('customer/session') but it does not have any function for gender.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you've created that attribute for customer, because as far as I know, magento doesn't provide this attribute by default.
So, try using this:

```
$customer->getResource()
          ->getAttribute('gender')
          ->getFrontend()
          ->getValue($customer);
```

It should work, or atleast, it did for me.